# indexing a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

A novice R user here. So i have a data set formated like:

```
    Date  Temp  Month
 1-Jan-90 10.56      1
 2-Jan-90 11.11      1
 3-Jan-90 10.56      1
 4-Jan-90 -1.67      1
 5-Jan-90  0.56      1
 6-Jan-90 10.56      1
 7-Jan-90 12.78      1
 8-Jan-90 -1.11      1
 9-Jan-90  4.44      1
10-Jan-90 10.00      1
```

In R syntax:

```
datacl <- structure(list(Date = structure(1:10, .Label = c("1990/01/01", 
  "1990/01/02", "1990/01/03", "1990/01/04", "1990/01/05", "1990/01/06", 
  "1990/01/07", "1990/01/08", "1990/01/09", "1990/01/10"), class = "factor"), 
      Temp = c(10.56, 11.11, 10.56, -1.67, 0.56, 10.56, 12.78, 
      -1.11, 4.44, 10), Month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
      1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Date", "Temp", "Month"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -10L))
```

i would like to subset the data for a particular month and apply a change factor to the temp then save the results.  so i have something like

```
idx <- subset(datacl, Month == 1)  # Index
results[idx[,2],1] = idx[,2]+change  # change applied to only index values
```

but i keep getting an error like

```
Error in results[idx[, 2], 1] = idx[, 2] + change: 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, give the change factor a value:

```
change <- 1
```

Now, here is how to create an index:

```
# one approach to subsetting is to create a logical vector: 
jan.idx <- datacl$Month == 1

# alternatively the which function returns numeric indices:
jan.idx2 <- which(datacl$Month == 1)
```

If you want just the subset of data from January,

```
jandata <- datacl[jan.idx,]
transformed.jandata <- transform(jandata, Temp = Temp + change)
```

To keep the entire data frame, but only add the change factor to Jan temps:

```
datacl$Temp[jan.idx] <- datacl$Temp[jan.idx] + change
```

Comment: Thanks! exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that `subset` does not produce an index, it produces a subset of your original dataframe containing all rows with `Month == 1`.

Then when you are doing `idx[,2]`, you are selecting out the `Temp` column.

```
results[idx[,2],1] = idx[,2] + change
```

But then you are using these as an *index* into `results`, i.e. you're using them as row numbers. Row numbers can't be things like `10.56` or `-1.11`, hence your error. Also, you're selecting the first column of `results` which is `Date` and trying to add temperatures to it.

There are a few ways you can do this.

You can create a logical index that is `TRUE` for a row with `Month == 1` and `FALSE` otherwise like so:

```
idx <- datac1$Month == 1
```

Then you can use that index to select the rows in `datac1` you want to modify (this is what you were trying to do originally, I think):

```
datac1$Temp[idx] <- datac1$Temp[idx] + change  # or 'results' instead of 'datac1'?
```

Note that `datac1$Temp[idx]` selects the `Temp` column of `datac1` and the `idx` rows.

You could also do

```
datac1[idx,'Temp']
```

or

```
datac1[idx,2]  # as Temp is the second column.
```

If you *only* want `results` to be the subset where `Month == 1`, try:

```
results <- subset(datac1, Month == 1)
results$Temp <- results$Temp + change
```

This is because `results` only contains the rows you are interested in, so there's no need to do subsetting.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed explanation. It helped me understand exactly what was going on. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would use `ifelse()` and leverage the syntactic beauty that is `within()` for a nice one liner `datacl <- within(datacl, Temp <- ifelse(Month == 1, Temp + change,Temp))`. Well, I said one liner, but you'd need to define `change` somewhere else too.

Comment: also just want to mention that you can nest `ifelse()` statements to account for other months or conditions.